# About @Dblookup

Tags: lotus-domino

My formula is this `@DbLookup("";"";"vwCompanyHR";1;"companyHR");`. 
However, it doesn't work. I can't get the value of the `companyHR` field in the `vwCompanyHR` view. In the `vwCompany view, when I change the`#` column in the sort label pick the standard in the category, it works. Then I find if pick the sort, it doesn't work again. Why this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned the "#" column. I'm taking a bit of a guess:  Is that column using "# in View" seelction from the simple function list?  (Or the equivalent formula: @DocNumber?)

If so, you should not use that as the key for an @DbLookup. It is a special 'unreadable' type.

Using a categorized column may have a side-effect of making it readable, but it's still a bad idea.